# How to check what activity is in intent to be stated

Tags: android, android-intent, comparison

I'm starting some activities (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`) and before activity `A3` is started I want an AlertDialog `myDialog` to be shown:

```
void startActivityCallback(Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals(A3.class.getName())){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Title Title")
        .setMessage("Message Message")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                callNegaitveMethod();
            }
        })
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .show();
    else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Is there any other way to do it?** I don't like comparing class by names:

```
if(intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals(A3.class.getName())){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a boolean flag in your intent using `putExtra`.
And then retrieve it back using `getBooleanExtra` and based on the value of this flag decide whether to show a dialog or not.